# select a value from several dataframes (file.csv) and merge them into a new dataframe with R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, tidyverse, cbind

Maybe I'm asking for something too simple, but I can't solve this problem.
I want to create a script that recursively enters the folders present in a `base_folder`, opens a specific file with a name that is always the same (`w3nu`) and selects a precise value (I need to select the email of the subject belonging to the `Response` column, filtering for the corresponding heat in the `Question.Key` column).

I want my script to repeat itself in the same way for all the folders present in the base folder.

Finally, I want to merge all the emails into a new dataframe.

I have created this script but it does not work.

```
 library(tidyverse)

base_folder <- "data/raw/exp_1_participants/sbj"

files <- list.files(base_folder, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
demo_email <- files[str_detect(files, "w3nu")]

email_extraction <- function(demo_email){
  
  demo_email <- read.csv(task,header = T)
  demo_email <- demo_email %>%
    filter(Question.Key == "respondent-email") %>%
    select(Response)
}
  
  email_list_jolly <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(demo_email))
  
  for(i in 1:length(email_list_jolly)){
email_list_jolly[[i]] <- email_extraction(demo_email[i])
  }
  
  email_list_stud <- cbind(email_list_jolly)
  
  write.csv(email_list_stud, 'data/cleaned/email_list_stud.csv')
```

can you help me? thanks

Comment: Without your data, it's hard to guess what exactly is going wrong. What's the output you actually get?

Comment: actually, I get this error: "Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument" and then the script crashes

Comment: @Dubukay I can add some more useful information to help you understand what is wrong? I don't know, maybe tell you how the db is structured

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined `task` within the script shown above, but you're telling `read.csv` to find it. Did you mean to pass `demo_email` to `read.csv` instead? `task` is probably a random vector in your workspace.

Comment: @Dubukay you're right! I renamed the vector but forgot to change the name there. How stupid, thank you! now it works! Just one more thing. In the file "email_list_stud.csv" i get `list(Response = "XXXX@gmail.com")`. Is there a way to get just the email? So a list of "XXXX@gmail.com" without "list(Response =...)"?

Comment: Try `pull` instead of `select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

Looks like you haven't defined task within the script shown above, but you're telling `read.csv` to find it. Did you mean to pass `demo_email` to `read.csv` instead? `task` is probably a random vector in your workspace.